# Trying to make a query to get all answers to all questions on a test

Tags: mysql

MySQL has never been my strong point. I've created an online application which allows users to create tests for other people to take, simply to see if they pass or fail. The database structure of these tests are as follows:

```
user_test
  - id (integer, primary key, auto increment)
  - owner (integer)

user_test_question
 - id (integer, primary key, auto increment)
 - belongs_to_test (integer)
 - question_text (varchar)

user_test_answer
 - id (integer, primary key, auto increment)
 - belongs_to_question (integer)
 - answer_text (integer)
 - answer_correct (integer)
```

Here's a Schema I created for a test scenario

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE user_tests (
  test_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  test_owner INT(11) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE test_questions (
  question_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  question_belongs_to INT(11) NOT NULL,
  question_text VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE test_answers (
  answer_id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  answer_belongs_to INT(11) NOT NULL,
  answer_text VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  answer_correct SMALLINT(1) DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO users (user_id) VALUES (NULL);

INSERT INTO user_tests(test_id, test_owner) VALUES (NULL, 1);
INSERT INTO test_questions(question_id, question_belongs_to, question_text) VALUES (NULL, 1, "first question");
INSERT INTO test_questions(question_id, question_belongs_to, question_text) VALUES (NULL, 1, "second question");
INSERT INTO test_questions(question_id, question_belongs_to, question_text) VALUES (NULL, 1, "third question");

INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 1, "Question 1 - answer 1", 0);
INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 1, "Question 1 - answer 2", 0);
INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 1, "Question 1 - answer 3", 0);

INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 2, "Question 2 - answer 1", 0);
INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 2, "Question 2 - answer 1", 0);

INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 3, "Question 3 - answer 1", 0);
INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 3, "Question 3 - answer 2", 0);
INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 3, "Question 3 - answer 3", 0);
INSERT INTO test_answers(answer_id, answer_belongs_to, answer_text, answer_correct) VALUES (null, 3, "Question 3 - answer 4", 0);
```

Here's the query I've tried using:

```
SELECT * FROM `user_tests`, `test_questions`, `test_answers`
WHERE `user_tests`.`test_owner` = 1 #The "user id" 
AND `test_answers`.`answer_id` = `test_questions`.`question_id`
GROUP BY `test_questions`.`question_id` 
ORDER BY `test_questions`.`question_id`
```

The results yielded only show one answer per question though, and expected results would be like so:

Answers listed in order of Question id, like so:

```
question_id: 1, answer_id: 1, text: Question 1 - Answer 1
question_id: 1, answer_id: 2, text: Question 1 - Answer 2
question_id: 1, answer_id: 3, text: Question 1 - Answer 3
question_id: 2, answer_id: 4, text: Question 2 - Answer 1
question_id: 2, answer_id: 5, text: Question 2 - Answer 2
question_id: 3, answer_id: 6, text: Question 3 - Answer 1
question_id: 3, answer_id: 7, text: Question 3 - Answer 2
question_id: 3, answer_id: 8, text: Question 3 - Answer 3
question_id: 3, answer_id: 9, text: Question 3 - Answer 4
```

Comment: I tried using SQLFiddle, but it's not working right now.

Comment: Don't use comma-join syntax. See JOINs

Comment: And all answers are "0" (i.e. incorrect)

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm aware as to the answers, it was just example data .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using `GROUP BY` on question_id. this will make it so that it shows only one row for each question, you have to remove this line in your query

Also you have the following line in the query:

```
AND `test_answers`.`answer_id` = `test_questions`.`question_id`
```

This doesn't seem correct to me? this should be the belongs_to_question?|

I rebuild the table in my own database (sqlfiddle experiences timeouts):

```
SELECT * FROM `user_tests`, `test_questions`, `test_answers`
WHERE `user_tests`.`test_owner` = 1 #The "user id" 
AND `test_answers`.`answer_belongs_to` = `test_questions`.`question_id`
ORDER BY `test_questions`.`question_id`, `test_answers`.`answer_id`
```

The answer_text of answer_id = 5 is incorrect though but i guess that's just a typo in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is your GROUP BY which is not needed. You would need it, for example, if you wanted to count the number of good answer **per question**

Second problem you will have is ORDER BY if you really want the output the way you put it. You will need to add second parameter for answer_id

As stated by Strawberry, it is better for readability if you use JOIN syntax (explicit) instead of multiple FROM (implicit)

```
SELECT question_id, answer_id, ...
FROM user_tests
INNER JOIN ON test_questions.question_belongs_to = user_tests.test_id
...
WHERE user_tests.test_owner = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you are looking for:

```
SELECT CONCAT('question_id: ',Q.`question_id`) AS QID, 
       CONCAT('answer_id: ', A.answer_id) AS AID, 
       CONCAT('Text: ', A.answer_text) AS Atxt
FROM `user_tests` T
INNER JOIN `test_questions` Q ON Q.`question_belongs_to` = T.`test_id` 
INNER JOIN `test_answers` A ON A.`answer_belongs_to` = Q.`question_id` 
WHERE T.`test_owner` = 1 #The "user id" 
ORDER BY Q.`question_id`

|            QID |          AID |                        Atxt |
|----------------|--------------|-----------------------------|
| question_id: 1 | answer_id: 1 | Text: Question 1 - answer 1 |
| question_id: 1 | answer_id: 2 | Text: Question 1 - answer 2 |
| question_id: 1 | answer_id: 3 | Text: Question 1 - answer 3 |
| question_id: 2 | answer_id: 4 | Text: Question 2 - answer 1 |
| question_id: 2 | answer_id: 5 | Text: Question 2 - answer 1 |
| question_id: 3 | answer_id: 6 | Text: Question 3 - answer 1 |
| question_id: 3 | answer_id: 7 | Text: Question 3 - answer 2 |
| question_id: 3 | answer_id: 8 | Text: Question 3 - answer 3 |
| question_id: 3 | answer_id: 9 | Text: Question 3 - answer 4 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95775/3)

You were using a `GROUP BY` and you don't need that if you want all answers.

Additionally you used *implicit join* syntax which is a bad habit, always use explicit JOIN syntax